# How to get FCM token in Cordova?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I try to implement push notification in android mobile app. Using

```
cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging
```

I can send push notification to android mobile using firebase console , but what happen those are installed apk file , all are receive push notifications, but i want to send to specific users, so i want to get FCM token.

What i am tried, in 'index.js' file, onDeviceReady function i call the below function to get token.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

    FCMPlugin.onTokenRefresh(function(token){
        alert( token );
    });

    FCMPlugin.getToken(function(token){
        alert(token);
    });

}
```

When i build and install apk file and open in mobile device, but nothing show when open device.
My Cordova version is 11.0.0
and installed plugin is

```
cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated 7.8.0 "Cordova FCM Push Plugin"
```

Any reply much appreciate.

Regards
Aravind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following script to initialize the firebase settings

```
<script type="module">
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-app.js";
        import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-analytics.js";
        // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
      
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
        const firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
          authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN (get it from your firebase project)",
          databaseURL: "YOUR_FIREBASE_DB_PATH",
          projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
          storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
          messagingSenderId: "YOUR_SENDERS_ID",
          appId: "YOUR_APP_ID",
          measurementId: "G-4TN45ZQFFJ"
        };
      
        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
      </script>
```

make sure you have done the following

1. Created a firebase project and taken the above code directly from your project settings window (firebase has given a provision where it displays that code above along with your credentials, simple copy that and paste on your index.html page)
2. Your google-services.json, which you have to download from your firebase project needs to be in the root directory.
3. Once all that is done, you need to use the below code:

cordova.plugins.firebase.messaging.getToken().then(function(token) {
//save the token in a table on your server. Send the payload to that token.

}

4. once you have the tokens saved and you send a notification, you will need to catch the notification as under.

   cordova.plugins.firebase.messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload)

   { //do something with the payload received/notification received

   ```
     }
   ```

Comment: Hi, could you explain point no 1 in detail , where to get that code from Project Setting in firebase console, when i open project setting i getting some tabs, from where i get that codes, SS https://prnt.sc/1jDZWPb35iaA

Comment: Hi, you have to see the documentation. Click on this link below. While using cordova, you must follow the settings for web and not android.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive?hl=en&authuser=0

Comment: Hi could you pls tell what are plugin need to add ? i try to create new app, and downloaded  google-services.json from fire base, i installed "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated 7.8.0 "Cordova FCM Push Plugin"  and my code is cordova.plugins.firebase.messaging.getToken().then(function(token) { alert(token);} , nothing i get token, is it any other plugin need to add ?

Comment: Remove that plugin. I have never heard of that plugin before. Install this plugin from here 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging

read the documentations carefully

Comment: I installed above mention plugin only, but still not getting device token, here i attach ss of plugin i installed https://prnt.sc/8tOHzySfV8T2  and in index.js Ss https://prnt.sc/DrNnjR40Gx7q

Comment: Once i add this plugin "cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging" and build i get this error Ss https://prnt.sc/O3-UvZWhOUTm

Comment: u haven't placed the google-services.json file in the root folder... place it in the root as well as platforms\android\app\src folder too and then build again

Comment: And btw... why don't you root your phone to android studio and use this command instead  cordova run android --verbose 

--verbose shows you all the errors in details 

you can also try --stacktrace

Comment: Yes thanks working now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249444/discussion-between-aravindb-and-riya-singh).

Answer (score 0):

You need to send it to Firebase using your back-end, by sending your notification to the Firebase endpoint `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

Comment: How to get firebase token in mobile device ? what are the plugins need to add ? this is the function to get token , but what plugin need to add ? cordova.plugins.firebase.messaging.getToken().then(function(token) { //save the token in a table on your server. Send the payload to that token.

}